# GetDate() only assigning date portion as default in column

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a datebase table has a datetime field. It uses GetDate() as a default. My c# is written using Ideablade (entity framework). When I save the record in my application. The GetDate() only populates the Date portion and sets the time portion to 00:00:00am. Is there an issue with the Entity Framework and the GetDate() default in the database?

Comment: Can you share the table's definition please?

Comment: Are you passing in a value for the column? My guess is your code is sending the value which means the default will be ignored on the database side.

Comment: My code does nothing with the datetime field. In Sql Server, it is set up as a datetime null with a GetDate() as the default value.

Comment: Well unless you can share the table definition and some code there isn't much anybody can do but speculate.

Comment: There's not really much to say here other than: Look carefully at what you're inserting, what the default constraint actually is and whether there's any triggers on the table.

Comment: what is the datatype of the field? Do you have a sample code from c#?can you add it here?